# Property 'next' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>'

Tags: angular5

I am learning angular 5 and I have been trying to use the .next method to add data.service.ts In trying this :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()

export class DataService {

  private go = new BehaviorSubject<any>([' First Goal','Second Goal']);

  newvar = this.go.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  changeGoal(newvar){
    this.newvar.next(this.go);
  }

}
```

and I got this error:  " Property 'next' does not exist on type 'Observable'  ";

Comment: I found this solution just change one line

" this.go.next(this.newvar); "

Comment: For future reference, the reason for the error is that `next(...)` is a member of RxJS subjects and not observables. This is why your solution above works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Property 'next' does not exist on type 'Observable<{}>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49401761/property-next-does-not-exist-on-type-observable)

Answer (score 9):

Since `.next()` is a property of a [`Subject`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/subject) and not of an `Object`, you should use `go.next()` instead of `this.newvar.next()`:

```js
changeGoal(newvar) {
    this.go.next(value);
}
```