# Property 'next' does not exist on type 'Observable<{}>'

Tags: angular, rxjs

trying to do the following

```
let o = new Observable() ;
o.delay( 3000 ).next( { stuff } ) ;
```

Getting the following error

> [ts] Property 'next' does not exist on type 'Observable<{}>'

also tried

```
Let o = new Subject(); 
o.delay( 3000 ).next( { stuff } ) ;
```

Still getting

> [ts] Property 'next' does not exist on type 'Observable<{}>'.

Comment: That's correct, `next` exists only on instances of the `Subject` class. If you chain Subject with an operator it returns an Observable and therefore you can't call `next`.

Comment: @martin how to delay next on Subject

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `next` on the `Subject` instance. The `o` variable from your example is then the Subject chained with the operator that returns an Observable.

```
const s = new Subject(); 
const o = s.delay(3000);

o.subscribe(...);

s.next();
```

Comment: i want to delay and add next prior to subscribe

Comment: @Pascal What's the difference?